# Importing test cases into TFS

Tags: tfs, import, targetprocess

I would like to move my test cases from an older system into the TFS system. I discovered the "Test Case Migrator Plus" tool, however after downloading & extracting zip file, I cannot find the TestCaseMigratorPlus.exe file. Project info can be found at: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tcmimport

Does anyone have suggestions on getting the the .exe file so I can begin the migration process? Are there other tools available to do this task? My test case data is in both cvs & xls format.

Comment: Have you tried using the copy/paste option into the "Add Test Case using Grid" option? https://jessehouwing.net/vsts-add-additional-fields-to-edit-test-case-grid/

Comment: Yes, I know about the copy/paste with grid displayed. However, I have quite a few tests to pull in. If that's my only option, then I will tackle it. For now, I was hoping I could import w/ the tool.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the archive zip file contains all the releases. But they're named a bit weird. Looking at the releases manifest you should be able to just rename this file `releases\0\427b6077-824e-48ef-8eed-8111cc2f7fbc` to `TestCaseMigratorPlus(Excel-MHT) V1.1 RTM Binaries.zip`:

```
  {
    "Id": "427b6077-824e-48ef-8eed-8111cc2f7fbc",
    "FileName": "TestCaseMigratorPlus(Excel-MHT) V1.1 RTM Binaries.zip",
    "Url": "./0/427b6077-824e-48ef-8eed-8111cc2f7fbc",
    "Type": "Application",
    "UploadDate": "2012-01-02T00:15:57.42-08:00"
  },
```